# How to install CyanogenMod on my HTC Desire SV

Tags: cyanogenmod

My HTC Desire SV isn't listed as a supported device for CyanogenMod. How can I get CyanogenMod to work on it?

I'm very new to this. So, I could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say, CyanogenMod is not working on this model and will not work in the future too.

You could find enough help from communities like xda-developers. One link that might help is: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2293155

There are some custom-rom developed by members of xda.

**Never ever ever ever forget to backup your stock ROM.**

There can be a lot of bugs in these customROM. Common issues found for desire aka MAGNI are screen flickering, wifi problem, sd-card not being detected etc.

I would suggest you to first root your mobile and try installing safeStrap bootloader as your first babysteps before taking a leap into installing the customROM. XDA is the only place where you could get this done.